# What is ".cygwin" extension file? I can't get any result from Google&Bing SEs and file-ext.org

Tags: c, cygwin

I found out a [project](https://github.com/codenotes/mf2t/tree/master) that there's a feat I want. But the proj owner didn't give any info about how to build it. There's a suspicious file called "MakeFile.cygwin".

yeah, yeah, I know, I know what is Cygwin and MakeFile.

But I never heard of .cygwin file extension... And my "make.exe" can't recognize it. And only returns:

```
"make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."
```

Mostly, what I've heard is `MakeFile.mak` or `MakeFile`.(But my case isn't.)

BTW, I installed the newest version of make.exe and other tools from Cygwin options.

Only if I could learn wat iz ".cygwin" file...

My objective is to build this shoot out. But am lack of knowledge about ".cygwin" ext.

Comment: `make` won't find that makefile by default -- you need to be explicit.  Try something like `make -f MakeFile.cygwin`.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you! New problem appeared. For me it's a progress. I'll mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Well, you can name a file pretty much any way you like. You could do a `file MakeFile.cygwin` to get an educated guess on the file type. From the name itself, the person who created the file most likely wanted to give the idea that this is a _makefile_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems who uploaded this code was using Cygwin and never wrote a general Makefile.

It is not unusual to find Makefiles for all type of platform.
This is what you could find on Postgresql source tree:

```
$ ls -1
Makefile
Makefile.aix
Makefile.cygwin
Makefile.darwin
Makefile.freebsd
Makefile.linux
Makefile.netbsd
Makefile.openbsd
Makefile.solaris
Makefile.win32
meson.build
pgxs.mk
```

Assuming you are not using Cygwin, copy the `Makefile.cygwin` to `Makefile` and modify it for your own platform